# Firebase/javascript -- How to connect data created in firestore with user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase v9

How to connect data created in firestore with user who created this data?

I use the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`
function to authorize user in firebase and after authorization I getting user data with `onAuthStateChanged`, but how could i connect particular user with data that is created only by them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create for example a profile document for a specific user, the common pattern is to use the user's UID as the document ID. Something like this:

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    const uid = user.uid;

    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
      name: user.displayName
    });
    // ...
  }
});
```

Also see:

- the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-9)
- the Firebase documentation on [writing a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)